# Generate all combinations of N items into two bags, whereby each item is in one or zero bags

Tags: python, algorithm, generator

I need to write a generator that returns every arrangement of items such that each is in one or none of two different bags. Each combination should be given as a tuple of two lists, the first being the items in bag1, and the second being the items in bag2.

I wrote the following code and it fails one test case. It says my implementation has more arrangements than in the correct answer. The second test case passes. I can't see which items the test cases are using, but I tried some values and it seems to work. Could someone please explain me what is wrong?

What I'm basically doing is removing the first item in the array and calling the function recursively with the rest. Then I yield all possible arrangements with the item previously removed (not adding it, adding it only to the first bag, adding it only to the second bag) for each arrangement returned by the recursion.

```
def yieldAllCombos(items):
    """
        Generates all combinations of N items into two bags, whereby each 
        item is in one or zero bags.

        Yields a tuple, (bag1, bag2), where each bag is represented as a list 
        of which item(s) are in each bag.
    """
    # Your code here
    if (items == []):
        yield ([], [])
    else:
        item = items[0]
        for result in yieldAllCombos(items[1:]):
            yield (result[0], result[1])
            yield (result[0] + [item], result[1])
            yield (result[0], result[1] + [item])
```

Comment: The items in your output lists are in reverse order from their original order in the `items` list. You can try making them following the input order instead with `yield ([item] + result[0], result[1])` and `yield (result[0], [item] + result[1])` to match the grader's expections.

Comment: You are right. Now it works. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @blhsing suggested, making the item the first element in the list fixed the problem.

```
def yieldAllCombos(items):
    """
        Generates all combinations of N items into two bags, whereby each 
        item is in one or zero bags.

        Yields a tuple, (bag1, bag2), where each bag is represented as a list 
        of which item(s) are in each bag.
    """
    # Your code here
    if (items == []):
        yield ([], [])
    else:
        item = items[0]
        for result in yieldAllCombos(items[1:]):
            yield (result[0], result[1])
            yield ([item] + result[0], result[1])
            yield (result[0], [item] + result[1])
```